# find alphabetic substring

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, substring

I have the following strings, from which i want to extract the alphabetic part (alphabetic substring) only which is greater than 1:

- % d. i.p.p. attendu --> attendu
- aprÃ ¨ s. expertise --> apr, expertise
- n.c.p.c. condamner --> condamner

I am trying the following piece code :

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
void main()
{
    const std::string s = "% d. i.p.p. attendu";
    std::regex rgx("[a-zA-Z]{2,20}");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx))
        std::cout << "match: " << match[1] << '\n';
}
```

But I am having the following error when i run the code :
**Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error' what(): regex_error**

Can you please help me,
Thank you,
Hani.

Ok I managed to use boost since gcc's regex is an **abomination**.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

void main()
{
        const std::string s = "% d. i.p.p. tototo attendu";
        boost::regex re("[a-zA-Z]{4,7}");
        boost::smatch matches;
        if( boost::regex_search( s, matches, re ) )
         {
               std::string value( matches[0].first, matches[0].second );
                cout << value << "  ";
          }
}
```

Fine i found attendu but the output is only tototo. It's not incrementing

The return value is  "tototo attendu" I was wondering if I can return each value at a time instead of 1 string

Comment: You're probably using GCC. Their regex implementation is an abomination.

Comment: Works with clang++(except `void main` and `match[1]` - should be `match[0]`).

Comment: The code looks okay. If you can use `clang++` or MSVC you'll get much better results.

Comment: (You can use Boost.Regex as a drop-in replacement for the missing GCC implementation.) / @PeteBecker GCC has *no* regex implementation, just function stubs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - as I said, it's an abomination. Maybe I should have put "implementation" in quotes. `<g>`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the `strings` utility that already does this?

Comment: No @Mark not at all. I'll look for it. All what i needed to do is to extract the alphabetic substrings that's all.

Comment: Well what i found out is that the problem is with the regular expression, I don't know what i am doing wrong: [a-zA-Z]{4,16}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if I can return each value at a time instead of 1 string

The only way of doing this seems to be via [`regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator). Here’s an example using Boost:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string s = "% d. i.p.p. tototo attendu";
    boost::regex rgx("([a-zA-Z]{2,20})");
    boost::smatch match;

    boost::sregex_iterator begin{s.begin(), s.end(), rgx},
                           end{};

    for (auto&& i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        std::cout << "match: " << *i << '\n';
}
```

This yields:

```
match: tototo
match: attendu
```

Two things:

- The return type of `main` is **always** `int`. Your code shouldn’t even compile.
- I’ve added parentheses around your (first, which was correct!) regular expression so that it creates a capture for each match. The iterators then iterate over each match in turn.

Comment: Thank you @Konrad, I was actually stuck in trying to modify the regular expression. I don't really understand the following parts:
if it's ok to ask:
in the for loop what is the meaning of : **auto&& i**

Comment: @HaniGoc In C++11 `auto` declares a variable and deduces its type from the initialisation. `&&`, in this context, is a [universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) – put simply, `auto&&` deduces the reference type of `i`. I could also have written `boost::sregex_iterator&` instead – but since `auto&&` is shorter, it’s generally preferred in range-for loops.